# Need to update Email template of MFA which is being sent to User

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am looking for solution/code/custom policy to customize/update email which is being sent over user email address when ever he is being instate MFA for his account login

SAMPLE FORMAT BELOW WHICH NEED TO BE UPDATED OVER EMAIL which is being sent to customer along with OTP

the subject and email format of the OTP for the customer onboarding process should be:

Subject of the email: XYZ Company registration - [OTP number] for authenticating user
Body of the email:

Thank you for initiating the process of registering to our XYZ company online. Please use the [OTP number] to validate your email address.

In case you have not raised this request, please contact our Customer Service Centre on 18000 077 or email Customer.Helpdesk@xyz.au and we will be more than happy to assist you.

Regards,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use **custom email in Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)** to send customized email to users that sign up to use your applications. By using the **third-party email provider SendGrid**, you can use **your own email template** and **From: address and subject, as well as support localization and custom one-time password (OTP) settings**.

Custom email verification requires the use of a **third-party email provider** like **[SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/), [Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/), or [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/)**, a **custom REST API**, or any **HTTP-based email provider (including your own)**

**Note:** Azure Active Directory B2C offers **two** methods to define how users interact with your applications: through predefined **[user flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview)** or through fully configurable **[custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview)**.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy):